# openssl_pkey_new and "error:0E064002:configuration file routines:CONF_load"

Tags: php, windows, openssl

I know this is a returning issue, but (as far as I found) all suggested solutions did not solve my issue - so I hope I get some additional info from "those who know..."

Setup:
I run Apache 2.4 with PHP 7.0.7 and OpenSSL 1.0.2h (all three the 64bit versions) on a Windows Server 2012 environment.

---

When I try to invoke PHP openssl_pkey_new function, I get those "system library:fopen:No such process" errors. Most of the recommondations point into the direction: "make sure openssl finds its config file". However in my case, I feel this is actually the case (see messages below):

1. when calling the function with an config array WITHOUT the "config" option, I get TWO sets of "no such process" error messages and a "bool (false)" result.
2. when calling the function WITH the respective "config" option, I get only ONE set of "no such process" error messages and an "Openssl KEY" ressource as result.

Therefore I belief that the config file actually is found, but something is wrong within the config file.

However I could not find sufficient help on how to pin-down the error within the configuration file - and that is where I need any kind of guidance...

**Errors before calling openssl_pkey_new**

If no errors above this line are shown, then there are NONE!
Config-Array for openssl_pkey_new function 
    Array
    (
    [digest_alg] => sha512
    [private_key_bits] => 4096
    [private_key_type] => 0
    )

**Calling openssl_pkey_new - with config-array but without CONFIG  !**

```
bool(false)
```

**Errors after calling openssl_pkey_new**

```
string(51) "error:02001003:system library:fopen:No such process"
string(53) "error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file"
string(63) "error:0E064002:configuration file routines:CONF_load:system lib"
string(51) "error:02001003:system library:fopen:No such process"
string(53) "error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file"
string(63) "error:0E064002:configuration file routines:CONF_load:system lib"
```

**Calling openssl_pkey_new - with config-array including CONFIG  !**

```
Array
(
[digest_alg] => sha512
[private_key_bits] => 4096
[private_key_type] => 0
[config] => C:\Webserver\OpenSSL\openssl.cfg
)
```

resource(4) of type (OpenSSL key)

**Errors after calling openssl_pkey_new**

```
string(51) "error:02001003:system library:fopen:No such process"
string(53) "error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file"
string(63) "error:0E064002:configuration file routines:CONF_load:system lib"
string(68) "error:0E06D06C:configuration file routines:NCONF_get_string:no value"
string(68) "error:0E06D06C:configuration file routines:NCONF_get_string:no value"
string(68) "error:0E06D06C:configuration file routines:NCONF_get_string:no value"
string(68) "error:0E06D06C:configuration file routines:NCONF_get_string:no value"
string(68) "error:0E06D06C:configuration file routines:NCONF_get_string:no value"
string(68) "error:0E06D06C:configuration file routines:NCONF_get_string:no value"
```

---

The config file follows...

Config file "C:\Webserver\OpenSSL\openssl.cfg"

```
#
# OpenSSL configuration file used ...
# This is mostly being used for generation of certificate requests.
#

openssl_dir = C:\\Webserver\\\OpenSSL   # Where Openssl runs
RANDFILE    = $openssl_dir\\.rnd

####################################################################
[ ca ]
default_ca   = CA_default     # The default ca section

####################################################################
[ CA_default ]

dir = $openssl_dir\\PEM # Where everything is kept
certs   = $dir\\ssl.cert    # Where the issued certs are kept
###crl_dir  = $dir\\ssl.crl # Where the issued crl are kept
database    = $dir\\index.txt   # database index file.
new_certs_dir   = $dir\\ssl.cert-new    # default place for new certs.

certificate = C:\\Webserver\\Apache2\\conf\\ssl.cert\\myown.cert.pem    # The CA certificate
serial  = $dir\\serial  # The current serial number
###crl  = crl_dir\\crl.pem  # The current CRL
private_key = D:\\ssl.key\\myown.private-key.pem    # The private key
###RANDFILE = $dir\\private.rnd # private random number file


x509_extensions = x509v3_extensions # The extentions to add to the cert
default_days    = 365   # how long to certify for
default_crl_days    = 30    # how long before next CRL
default_md  = sha256    # which md to use.
preserve    = no    # keep passed DN ordering

# A few difference way of specifying how similar the request should look
# For type CA, the listed attributes must be the same, and the optional
# and supplied fields are just that :-)
policy  = policy_match

# For the CA policy
[ policy_match ]
countryName = match
stateOrProvinceName = match
organizationName    = match
organizationalUnitName  = optional
commonName  = supplied
emailAddress    = optional

# For the ’anything’ policy
# At this point in time, you must list all acceptable ’object’
# types.
[ policy_anything ]
countryName     = optional
stateOrProvinceName = optional
localityName    = optional
organizationName    = optional
organizationalUnitName  = optional
commonName  = supplied
emailAddress    = optional

####################################################################
[ req ]
default_bits    = 4096
encrypt_key = no
default_md  = sha256    # which md to use.
distinguished_name  = req_distinguished_name
attributes  = req_attributes

[ req_distinguished_name ]
countryName =   Country Name (2 letter code)
countryName_min =   2
countryName_max =   2
countryName_default =   AT
stateOrProvinceName =   State or Province Name (full name)
stateOrProvinceName_default =   Wien
localityName    =   Locality Name (eg, city)
localityName_default    =   Wien
organizationName    =   Organization Name (eg, company)
organizationName_default    =   MyOwn
organizationalUnitName  =   Organizational Unit Name (eg, section)
organizationalUnitName_default  =   Webservices
commonName  =   Common Name (eg, your website domain name)
commonName_max  =   64
commonName_default  =   www.yourdomain.com
emailAddress    =   Email Address
emailAddress_max    =   40
emailAddress_default    =   webmaster@mycompany.com

[ req_attributes ]
challengePassword     = A challenge password
challengePassword_min    = 4
challengePassword_max    = 20

[ x509v3_extensions ]
```

Comment: Forgot to mention: I did set OPENSSL_CONF pointing to "C:\Webserver\OpenSSL\openssl.cfg" as a systemwide environmental variable (with setx).